# Udp Routing with 2 ports

Tags: 14.04, networking, iptables, routing

I'm trying to pull udp stream to my ubuntu 14.04 and can't handle routing.

I'm having 2 ports
 1. is port with internet connection(local adress)
 2. is port with udp multicast streams with dynamic address.

What would I like to accomplish is that I pull udp streams to port 1 without impact on my internet connection.

I have managed to make it work but having lot of problems with internet connection..

**Current proggress :**
Created table download and rest of conf is in /etc/network/interfaces

```
 # The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto em2
iface em2 inet static
 address 192.168.1.100
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.1.1
 network 192.168.1.0
 dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
   post-up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev em2 src 192.168.1.100 table download
   post-up ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev em2 table download
   post-up ip rule add from 192.168.1.100/32 table download
   post-up ip rule add to 192.168.1.100/32 table download

auto p1p2
iface p1p2 inet dhcp
  hwaddress ether 88:A1:B1:AD:B5:A7
  post-up ip route change via 0.0.0.0 dev p1p2
```

Greetings,
Sadam

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have done so far and we'll go from there. Ubuntu 14.04 is past end of life, but that isn't relevant to your question.

Comment: Hello Doug, can you check it now?

Greetings

Comment: is port 1 em2 and port 2 p1p2? Where is the dhcp server that gives p1p2 its IP address? what does "pull udp streams to port 1" mean? I think this can all be done with iptables, but not sure yet.